# Using exhaustive optimization algorithms for Regression Function in Python

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, statistics, regression

I have to use the least squares method and the leave-one-out cross-validation to estimate the
mean square error of the regressions:
[Regression Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esx7k.png)

for p going from 1 to 30, and find out what is the best number for p in order to perform the best regression, defining what is the best value of p for building my regression function.

The problem is that I really don't know how to do this, at all. I understand all the math behind, I can do it by hand, I know Python, but I have something like a mental block. The Scikit Learn has something to help? I know they have Lasso and Ridge for feature selection but this is like doing a feature selection by hand, and I need something to compute the weights of the functions for each value of p and also compute their least square error. The problem is that my data has only one feature x, and I’m applying for several values of p. Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: I read it but the problem is that the question I need to formalize doesn't require me to write down any code. I need help to formalize this formula in code and iterate thru it, I'm not asking for tutorial resources or research, I'm asking about how to use exhaustive optimizations algorithms for regression functions in Python, I only add more information in order to make things more clear! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the question sufficient to write this example code, it uses your equation on some of my test data - you will need to replace the test data with your own data. This code should at least get you started. This example uses the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution module to automatically generate initial parameter estimates for the non-linear solver, and graphs the result with matplotlib.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(x, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, B2p1, B2p, p):
    returnVal = B0 # start with B0 and add the other terms

    returnVal += B1 * numpy.sin(2.0 * numpy.pi * x)
    returnVal += B2 * numpy.cos(2.0 * numpy.pi * x)

    returnVal += B3 * numpy.sin(2.0 * numpy.pi * 2.0 * x)
    returnVal += B4 * numpy.cos(2.0 * numpy.pi * 2.0 * x)

    returnVal += B2p1 * numpy.sin(2.0 * numpy.pi * p * x)
    returnVal += B2p * numpy.cos(2.0 * numpy.pi * p * x)

    return  returnVal


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # seach bounds for B0
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # seach bounds for B1
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # seach bounds for B2
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # seach bounds for B3
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # seach bounds for B4
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # seach bounds for B2p1
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # seach bounds for B2p
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # seach bounds for p

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# generate initial parameter values
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)

print('Parameters', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will start working on it from this example!